# Is it possible to use ES5 JavaScript with Angular 2 instead of TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, angular

Is it needed to learn TypeScript for Angular 2?

Can Angular 2 be used with plain JavaScript ?

Edit: I've seen that the languages used as ES6, ES7, Dart compile to JavaScript to be executed, but I haven't seen any reference to use ES5 JavaScript directly.

Comment: You can only use javascript. look at angular.io. ES6 == JavaScript but angular 2.0 can also be written in ES5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Go read this [guide](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/setup.html). Pressing the `ES5` tab on the code examples will show you regular ES5 JavaScript, as apposed to TypeScript.

The [API preview](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/) is, for obvious reasons, incomplete though. So you may not find the ES5 methods listed there yet, and some of it may change before release.

Current example of Angular 2.0 main component in ES5.

```
function AppComponent() {}

AppComponent.annotations = [
  new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
    selector: 'my-app'
  }),
  new angular.ViewAnnotation({
    template: '<h1>My first Angular 2 App</h1>'
  })
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  angular.bootstrap(AppComponent);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the example is too many clicks from the front page. This makes understand the annotations much better.

Comment: I came back to this question to respond to a comment on my own answer. Unfortunately this guide is quite dated. It probably was correct at the time of Oka's answer, but, for example, if you look at the angular script tag, it says alpha 26. It also puts the template in view annotation, where it can go to component now.

Comment: The guide link is dead.

Comment: actually both links are dead. I wander if this means that you now MUST use Typescript?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

Here are 2 simple components, written in different ways that Angular 2 supports when writing in JavaScript (EcmaScript 5):

```js
(function() {

  var HelloWorldComponent = function() {};

  HelloWorldComponent.annotations = [
    new ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'hello-world',
      template: '<h1>Hello Angular2!</h1>'
    })
  ];

  var HelloFlentApi = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'hello-fluent',
    template: '<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>' + '<input [(ngModel)]="name">',
  }).Class({
    constructor: function() {
      this.name = "Fluent API";
    }
  });

  var AppComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'company-app',
    template: '<hello-world></hello-world>' +
      '<hello-fluent></hello-fluent>',
    directives: [HelloWorldComponent, HelloFlentApi]
  }).Class({
    constructor: function() {}
  });

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(AppComponent);
  });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>

<company-app>
  Loading ...
</company-app>
```

I wrote a detailed explanation of the code here:

[Writing An Angular2 Component in Today’s JavaScript (ES5) – Beta 0 Edition](http://gurustop.net/blog/2015/12/16/angular2-beta-javascript-component)

As the link says, this applies to Angular 2 Beta 0, which was released a few hours ago at the time of writing this answer.

Comment: You used directives in your answer, I believe these are removed and also use of classes is a part of es6.

Comment: `directives` is not removed. It's just that you don't need to use them for built-in directives (`ngIf`, `ngFor`, etc) anymore. Also on use of classes, the `Class` in the code is a **function** available on the object returned by `ng.core.Component(...)`, not the `class` keyword from ES6.

Comment: Note that Angular 2 has the concept of directives too. They are not the same directives of Angular 1 though. If you look at the filters of the search page in Angular 2 docs, you'll see "Directive" is the first filter https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?apiFilter= - Components themselves are special kind of (think child classes of) Angular 2 directives.

Comment: To learn more about directives in Angular 2 check Attribute Directives  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html and Structural Directives https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html - It mentions that components are structural directives.

Comment: It means classes here is a function which is taking an object with constructor function as a parameter, I.e they have provided a workaround for es6 classes, also directives of angular 1 with isolate scopes, links, controllers are actually removed and replaced with much simpler components

Comment: Exactly. Component are behavioral directives, a totally new Angular 2 thing that happens to be called the same because it kinda does the same thing (DOM manipulation). Components are very good abstraction on top of Angular 2 directives so you are almost always encouraged to use them not use directives directly. This abstraction leaks a bit that you use the `directives` property of the component annotation even to mention custom components used in your template.

Comment: The reason you don't need to use `directives` property in component annotation for things like `ngIf`, `ngFor` anymore is that those are all now included in something called `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES`, which is now included by default for all components. You can extend this object on your own and add more directives/components without specifying them explicitly. The manual shows it here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/compiler/PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES-let.html

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to write plain javascript es5 components:

```
(function() {

    var MyComponent = ng.
        Component({
            selector: 'my-component'
        })
        .View({
            templateUrl: 'my-component.html'
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function () {
                this.someArray = [];
            },
            someCustomFunction: function(item) {
                this.someArray.push(item);
                ...
            }
        })

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        ng.bootstrap(MyComponent);
    });

})();
```

Here is a simple [todo list demo](http://www.angulartodo.com) using Javascript es5.

Answer (score 3):

Angular 5 dropped support for plain ES5.

See the following commit and comment on GitHub:
https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/cac130eff9b9cb608f2308ae40c42c9cd1850c4d

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731044/angular-5-with-es5/47731407#47731407

Answer (score 2):

Below is another example in Plain Javascript based on the Angular2 "Tour of Heroes". It is the copy of the DashboardComponent that you can find in the Angular2 tutorial (you can find the full Angular2 tutorial in Plain Javascript here http://programming.sereale.fr):

```
//= require services/heroes-service

var DashboardComponent = ng.core.Component({
    template: "<h3>Top Heroes</h3> \
                <div class='grid grid-pad'> \
                  <div *ngFor='#hero of heroes' (click)='gotoDetail(hero)' class='col-1-4' > \
                    <div class='module hero'> \
                      <h4>{{hero.name}}</h4> \
                    </div> \
                  </div> \
                </div>"
}).Class({
    constructor: [
      HeroService, ng.router.Router, ng.http.Http, function(heroService, router, http) {
        this._heroService = heroService;
        this._router = router;
        this._http = http;
      }
    ],
    ngOnInit: function() {
      //we get the list from mock-heroes.js
      //this._heroService.getHeroes.then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1,5)) 

      //we get the list from the server
      this._heroService.getHeroes(this._http).subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1,5));
    },
    gotoDetail: function(hero) { this._router.navigate(['HeroDetail', { id: hero.id }]); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript will be just a superset of ES6. And ES6 is a superset of ES5. Which means, ES5 is valid TypeScript and ES6 after all. Despite some specific features, for now a lot of what we get from those languages is syntactic sugar.

Here's an article that shows you [how to write Angular 2 code in ES5](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/09/writing-angular-2-code-in-es5.html).

Answer (score 1):

@jordiburgos 
**Is it needed to learn TypeScript for Angular 2?**
It is the recommended language by the angular team, and i can say from personal experience, that using es5 in a medium to large projects can be very hard to maintain over time because of its lack of key features like typing, classes and inheritance.

**Can Angular 2 be used with plain JavaScript ?**
Yes, and you have some good examples above.
Consider it carefully, go and review a comparisons like this one:
https://johnpapa.net/es5-es2015-typescript/