# Using Angular 2 without TypeScript Transpiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I want to learn Angular 2 and switch my app to using it, however, I'm having a problem with using TypeScript.

In my current environment I can't use a use the transpiler / compiler. I'm currently having to run off of just the node.js executable (node.exe) but not the full node.js application, nor npm. Angular 2 is written in TypeScript, so it needs to be compiled to JavaScript before being sent to the browser.

Is there a way to get a pre-compiled version of Angular 2 so I can write in JavaScript and run without a compiler?

If not, is there any way to manually install and use the TypeScript compiler with just the node.exe executable?

To be clear, this isn't because I don't want to use TypeScript, but rather because in my current situation I can't install it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use ES5 JavaScript with Angular 2 instead of TypeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689094/is-it-possible-to-use-es5-javascript-with-angular-2-instead-of-typescript)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Angular2 is available in TypeScript, JavaScript and Dart. No need to use TypeScript.

See
- https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/index.html
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/09/writing-angular-2-code-in-es5.html
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/06/even-better-es5-code-for-angular-2.html

See also [Is it possible to use ES5 JavaScript with Angular 2 instead of TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689094/is-it-possible-to-use-es5-javascript-with-angular-2-instead-of-typescript)

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.3/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.3/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.3/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: im not talking about what i write my code in im talking about angular 2 itself if you look at angular 2 beta its writen in typescript so it needs typescript to run even if i don't have to use typescript

Comment: No, it is written in TypeScript. The JS and Dart version is auto-generated from TypeScript and they are available in JS and Dart source.

Comment: where is the JS source? i cant find it anywhere

Comment: no i know that i can use javascript with angular that isnt my problem my problem is that i have no way to compile angular 2 itself to javascript

Comment: and i need a downloadable version of it because i can't use external domains. i need to run it off of my server.

Comment: See my updated answer with the Angular js script tags.

Comment: You can download it from the urls in the script tag.

Comment: No one mentions that even though you technically can write Angular 2 apps in plain javascript, it's a huge hassle since there are no decorators and you end up spending more time hacking and figuring out how to do things than developing your actual app. Not to mention the (still) lacking documentation for JS... If you make Angular 2 apps, I would stick to TypeScript. If you want to use JavaScript, probably best to stick with Angular 1 or another framework like Vue.

Comment: @AdamReis I'm not sure if that is correct. It looks like both Typescript and Javascript (ECMScript6) support and use decorators. (Perhaps this wasn't the case in 2017, when you wrote your comments). see https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-typescript-vs-ecmascript-6/

Comment: @bvdb Actually, decorators are still not present in (vanilla) Javascript as of today. The proposal is still in stage 2, see https://github.com/tc39/proposals

Comment: @AdamReis it is not really so huge problem, you can still use ng.core to add Components and so. See http://nicholasjohnson.com/blog/how-to-do-everything-in-angular2-using-es6/

Comment: I'm sure there's workarounds and things may have gotten (a lot) better since I wrote my comment a year and a half ago :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use TypeScript to write your application, you need a transpiler:

- static. For example with a `tsc -w` command running in background
- on the fly. Directly within the browser using the typescript.js file

That said it's possible to write Angular2 applications with ES5 only. Here is a sample:

- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/06/even-better-es5-code-for-angular-2.html

**Edit**

When you include these JavaScript files fro Angular2 (folder `node_modules/angular2/bundles`), there is nothing about TypeScript:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

These files were transpiled into JavaScript. So there is no need to have TypeScript. With them, you can implement your application with ES6 only.

To use ES5 only, you need to include these ones:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd tell the OP to at least give it a shot, TypeScript makes it so much easier since the IDE auto completes for you

Comment: my problem is that angular 2 is written in typescript so i cant use angular because i cant install typescript. if i could install typescript i would

Comment: Yes, Angular2 is written in TypeScript but when you include corresponding bundled JavaScript files, you don't need TypeScript since they were compiled into ES5