# How Do I Create A Reusable Component in Angular 2 Without Typescript

Tags: angular

In the examples I've found for Angular 2, components can be created once per app as such:

```
(function(app) { 
  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {}
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

with app/main.js bootstrapping the component:

```
(function(app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

But how would I define a reusable component? Documentation seems be written in Typescript or for Angular 1.

Comment: Docs for ESx are work in progress.

Comment: Yes, documentation is a WiP, which is why I was looking for help here :)

Comment: That's fine of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Every component is reusable by default. You can use it as `directive` inside of other component's template like `<my-app></my-app>` (Maybe not the best idea with root app component but with anything else like `<my-user-details [user]="user"></my-user-details>`). Another way to reuse components is when using Angular 2 router to navigate to same components with different route configs.

It all depends on how you build your components, usually you end up with `smart` (with functionality) and `dumb` (layout only) components where dumb will be reused the most.

Comment: You're right, the use of my-app was not illustrative of what I wanted to achieve. 
I think my confusion was with setting window.app.AppComponent (it's been a while since I've looked at doing this without TS). 
Because the examples I found were all for single use components like a page I read it as if app.AppComponent was an instance of the component rather than the component class to be instantiated later.
I think I need to go back and do some more tests.

Comment: I will after I've had the chance to test this solves my problem.

Comment: I'm having trouble still, but I'm sure it's something stupid. I found an earlier question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689094/is-it-possible-to-use-es5-javascript-with-angular-2-instead-of-typescript) where someone covered directives with ES5. I'll have to wait until tomorrow until I can test some more before I can mark this as answered. The frustrating part is that I can work with directives in Typescript but my work doesn't want to use polyfills for some reason!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been flat out.  I'm pretty sure [THIS](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) is the document I'm after, but it's still a WIP. As soon as I have two of the same component the site breaks. `directives: [ app.AppOtherComponent ]` doesn't seem to work. Got any idea what the syntax is? Cheers.