# is it possible to run angular2 with out using typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
  > ## Is it possible to run angular 2 with out using typescript? ##
```

I am trying to learn angular 2, now my question is before learning angular 2 typescript learning is mandatory or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use ES5 JavaScript with Angular 2 instead of TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689094/is-it-possible-to-use-es5-javascript-with-angular-2-instead-of-typescript)

Comment: yea of course it's possible, but just don't do this to yourself. Typescript is very easy, it's just javascript plus more features. Your life will be miserable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not mandatory, but I would learn it if you want to get better in the framework. The things you will learn are used in many other languages, so you will not only learn "Typescript".

You can start learning Angular with their [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) and you will start to understand some things of Typescript, then try to understand both.

Comment: Besides, Typescript (being a superset of Javascript and transpiling eventually to JS) can be used to write tougher NodeJS code.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to learn angular 2, now my question is before learning
>   angular 2 typescript learning is mandatory or not?

No, you can run angular2 without typescript.

See here: [Link](https://angular.io/docs#assumptions)

But Angular's doesn't provide much samples using JavaScript

Comment: Thank you for Your Response.