# Angular 5 with es5

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular 4 supports below syntax

```
var HelloComponent = ng.core
 Component({
    selector: 'hello-cmp',
    template: 'Hello World!',
    viewProviders: [Service]
  .Class({
   constructor: [Service, function (service) { 
   },`
  });
```

In Angular 5 , Class is missing anyone can provide Angular 5 with ES5 syntax currently 
i am not able to switch ES6 so please avoid that suggestion. 
if switching to ES6 is the only way then i will stick to angular 4 as of now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use static properties `annotations` and `parameters` on your component <strike>class</strike> function something like this:

```
function Service() {}

function AppComponent(service) {
  console.log(service);
}

AppComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function() {
  console.log('test ngOnInit');
};

AppComponent.annotations = [
  new Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Example of Angular  5.0.5 in ES5</h1>',
    viewProviders: [Service]
  })
];

AppComponent.parameters = [ Service ];
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ri98Nck5tYaHvBy44oWo?p=preview)**

Comment: are there changes for Angular6 with JS ES5?